# Hibernate Returns Different Time Stamps

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, timestamp, debian

We are using hibernate 4.3.0.Final to retrieve information from postgresql 9.4. when we query the database through pgadmin we see table entries stable but when we do the same queries through hibernate we get timestamps going back and forth 3 hours. Our database keeps timestamps without timezone and we are located at +3 timezone. We are unable to understand why hibernate altering time stamps even it happens when we use native queries.

Note: We are using Debian Jessie 8 and Tomcat 8

Table:

```
uid serial NOT NULL
time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
type smallint NOT NULL
```

pom conf:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: application & db are on same server or different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate uses the "JVM timezone" for date representations. If not set explicitly it the JVM uses the timezone set on the operating system.
You can tell your JVM which timezone to use on startup with the parameter

`-Duser.timezone=UTC`.

Answer (score 2):

Your jvm has timezone +3, try to

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

But it's a quick hack,you can do the timezone coverting at your dao layer

Comment: It works but there are so many dao classes in my project :) so im going to use Jürden solution. Thanks